# Split camel case string with untouched units in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to take a string in the format

```
SystolicArterialPressure(mmHg)
```

to

```
Systolic Arterial Pressure (mmHg)
```

which is essentially splitting on camelcase and at the parenthesis opening, but not on anything inside the parenthesis. I'm terrible at regex expressions and was hoping for some help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable writing a regex for this why do you want to include it in your code rather than doing the same with classical string manipulation (which I assume is more familiar)?

Comment: Because it will be a pain to do this without regex?

Comment: While I may not be the best at them, I'd like to try and get better. I just thought a one line regex would be better than writing a string manipulating algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = "SystolicArterialPressure(mmHg)";

$newString = preg_replace("/([A-Z].[^A-Z(]+)/s", "$1 ", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to add space before any capital letter alphabet which was not inside `()` or just after to the starting point.

```
(?:(?<=\()[^)]*|^[A-Z])(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Z]|\()
```

Replacment pattern,

```
 \1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uJ1vX5/4)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$string = 'SystolicArterialPressure(mmHg)';
$pattern = "~(?:(?<=\()[^)]*|^[A-Z])(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Z]|\()~";
$replacement = " $1";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
Systolic Arterial Pressure (mmHg)
```

Comment: This is great too, I think I'm going to use this in another area where they want the units next to the name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to insert a space whereever you match:

- Any consecutive word string with an `[[:uppper:]]` case letter at the beginning and `[[:lower:]]+` letters following.
- Or just anything in parens `\(.*?\)`. Once consumed the regex will not look into that again anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, it wouldn't split at the left parens and it would also put an undesired split inside the parens on the units.

Comment: Like I said, it automatically skips over the parens context once consumed. No need to make it any more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

i give it a try in php :) and crack a nut with a sledgehammer

```
$string = 'SystolicArterialPressure(mmHg)';

$newString = implode('', array_map(function($word, $break){
    if( strstr($word,'(') ) $break = true;
    if( $break ) return $word;
    return $word . ' ';
}, preg_split('#(?=[A-Z(])#s',$string), array(false)));

echo $newString;
```